# How to perform a simple while loop and parse blocks of binary data with nom?

Tags: rust, nom

Considering a binary file organized as segments of data, where the first 4 bytes are the segment type and the next 4 bytes are the segment length, and the remaining bytes are raw data. I can parse the first segment like:

```
named!(my_parser<&[u8], SomethingParsed>, do_parse!(
    segment_type: take!(4)      >>
    segment_length: be_u32      >>
    segment_data: take!(segment_length) >>

    (SomethingParsed {segments: ?})
))
```

How can I repeat that step until I reach the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`many0`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.2.3/nom/macro.many0.html) to apply a parser 0 or more times (or `many1` if you require at least one pass).

```
named!(my_iterated_parser<&[u8], Vec<SomethingParsed>>, many0!(my_parser));
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/doc/choosing_a_combinator.md)